# C# MongoDB BulkWriteAsync throws System.InvalidCastException

Tags: c#, mongodb, serialization, mongodb-.net-driver

We are getting a `System.InvalidCastException` when trying to save objects to our MongoDB. The error is sporadic but also makes no sense. The error message is:

> Unable to cast object of type 'MongoDB.Bson.BsonObjectId' to type 'MongoDB.Bson.BsonBoolean'.

From what I can tell in our code, we are not trying to convert an object Ids to booleans.
Our update code is something like this:

```
foreach (var update in updates)
{
    update.UpdateVersionNumber();
    var updateFilterDef = Builders<AmazonOrder>.Filter;
    var updateFilter = updateFilterDef.Eq(o => o.Id, update.Id) &
        (updateFilterDef.Eq(o => o.Version, update.LoadedVersion) |
            updateFilterDef.Exists(o => o.Version, false));
        list.Add(new ReplaceOneModel<AmazonOrder>(updateFilter, update));
}
```

Then we simply call:

```
var result = await _context.Orders.BulkWriteAsync(list, cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
```

The Stack trace we have is:

```
bool AsBooleanGetter(object)
Called from: JsonPropertyInfoOfT.cs in bool JsonPropertyInfo<T>.GetMemberAndWriteJson(object obj, ref WriteStack state, Utf8JsonWriter writer)
```

What would be causing this issue?

Comment: you should provide more details, types definitions, what is `UpdateVersionNumber` and in general more full repro

Comment: Can you please give us some models to work with? I have no idea what the types are supposed to be.